# Is it possible to bootstrap MIT scheme from portable C to native?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Just as an experiment, I've tried to bootstrap MIT Scheme, starting with the Portable C distribution.

I built the first installation using `etc/make-liarc.sh` followed by `make install`. This built and installed a working (supposedly) MIT Scheme. The dox say this is not a native build.

So... I unpack the unix source distribution, and do `configure` and `make` which barfs after building the runtime, sf, cref, and the compiler, complaining that "./tools/syntaxer.com" is not installed as part of the above installation.

So... I unpack the unix source distro again, and try `etc/make-native.sh`. That builds the runtime, sf, and cref, then barfs while trying to compile the compiler. It complains about an unbound variable cref/generate-trivial-constructor.

My question -- is it possible to bootstrap from the Portable C distribution to a native build? If so, how?

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and programmer effort.

Comment: From some research, I've found that make-native.sh is the "correct" way to do it but has been broken since 2013. So, the answer is "not with the provided tools."